# Validar input decimales con coma

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-validate

quisiera validar decimales con coma, o como agregar coma a los caracteres permitidos con esta validación, he podido validar enteros pero no decimales (con coma)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="enteros" type=text />
<input class="decimales" type=text />

$(function () {
            $('.enteros').on('input', function () {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            });
        });


$(function () {
                $('.decimales').on('input', function () {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente añade la `,` a los caracteres de la expresión regular:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.enteros').on('input', function () {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    });

  $('.decimales').on('input', function () {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="enteros" type=text />
<input class="decimales" type=text />
```

Comment: Si, gracias. ¿Existe forma de limitar el uso de la coma  a una por input y que solo se use luego de por lo menos 1 caracter? para evitar que se ingresen combinaciones como estas [,,,11][121,11,2,1][,]

Comment: Para evitar una segunda coma podrías controlar el evento `keypress` y cancelarlo si es una coma y ya existe una. Para una validación completa yo esperaría al evento `change` una vez que el usuario ha finalizado de editar el campo